# Selenium Webdriver get input value which already has value attribute (Java)

Tags: javascript, java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to parse a table containing input elements in it. Using Selenium WebDriver I get the list of input elements to extract their values:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "xpathSelector")
private List<WebElement> table;
```

An example of input element I have:

```
<input id="pt1:r1:3:detailTable:1:j_idt680::content"
name="pt1:r1:3:detailTable:1:j_idt680" style="text-align: right;color:#333333;"
class="af_inputText_content" type="text" value="1,000.00">
```

Iterating through input web elements I need to get each value.

```
List<String> inputValues = new ArrayList<>();
for (WebElement input : table) {
    inputValues.add(getValue(input));
}
```

I could use

```
input.getAttribute("value");
```

But this doesn't work because input elements already have a defined attribute "value".

I found out that in this case I can use JavaScript. This is the code I'm trying:

```
public String getValue(input) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    return js.executeScript("return arguments[0].value", element).toString();
}
```

But instead of real values I get **"dirty"** which doesn't make any sense.

I was able to get the real value in debugger mode using:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.evaluate(\"xpathSelector\",
document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue.value")
.toString()
```

How can I get values through JavascriptExecutor using already found by Selenium Webdriver WebElements?

**UPDATE:** I found a workaround for the issue using css selector but I don't like it:

```
    public String getNthInputValueByCss(String cssSelector, int elementNumber) {
    String jsScript = String.format("return document.querySelectorAll(\"%s\")[%d].value", cssSelector, elementNumber);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    return js.executeScript(jsScript).toString();
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the difference between `return arguments[0].value` and `input.getAttribute("value");` I think both would retrieve the same data. The difference is just technical or am I missing something?

Comment: @Würgspaß unfortunately not. input.getAttribute("value") will return a value only if an element does not have defined attribute "value". The following is the example of an input I have and it already have attribute 'value':
<input id="pt1:r1:3:detailTable:1:j_idt680::content" name="pt1:r1:3:detailTable:1:j_idt680" style="text-align: right;color:#333333;" class="af_inputText_content" type="text" value="1,000.00">

Comment: Does the page you're testing have jQuery?

Comment: @Josh No. The page doesn't have jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the value attribute through javascript first before getting the value attribute? It's also a workaround but maybe you'll like that more?

Comment: this might be a solution but I assume not an elegant one. Is it a good practice to change DOM during testing?

BTW check out the solution that I found.

Comment: You mean the css selector one? Or the one with xpath for javascript? By the way, what do you mean by this: How can I get values through JavascriptExecutor using already found by Selenium Webdriver WebElements?

Answer (score 0):

My further research lead me to a solution with the use of cssSelector.

From the documentation to Selenium WebDriver `executeScript(String script, Object... args)` method:

> The arguments will be made available to the JavaScript via the
>   "arguments" magic variable, as if the function were called via
>   "Function.apply"
>
> Arguments must be a number, a boolean, a String, WebElement, or a List
>   of any combination of the above.
>
> @param args The arguments to the script. May be empty

**Solution:**

So we can pass our `WebElement element` as one of the arguments of `executeScript()` method and then use the argument to search among children of our `element`.

```
protected String getInputValue(WebElement element) {
    String js = "return arguments[0].querySelector('input').value";
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    return js.executeScript(js, element).toString();
}
```