# {WebElement}.getAttribute("value") returns 0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am interacting with an element within a webpage:

```xml
<li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root jss524 MuiMenuItem-gutters jss525 MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-divider MuiListItem-button" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-disabled="false" data-quid="SelectListItem-2" value=“{URL}”>
  <div class="jss519">
    <div class="jss520">
      <div>{TEXT}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="jss522"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
</li>
```

Within my code, I have this snippet:

```java
System.out.println(x.getAttribute("role"));
System.out.println(x.getAttribute("aria-disabled"));
System.out.println(x.getAttribute("data-quid"));
System.out.println(x.getAttribute("class"));
System.out.println(x.getText());
System.out.println(x.getAttribute("value"));
```

However, the last line `System.out.println(x.getAttribute("value"));` prints out 0 instead of the actual value.

I am using selenium 3.141.59

Comment: What is your `x` here and how are you identifying your element.

Comment: Could be that you are getting the incorrect element via the findElement function

Comment: @SameerArora WebElement x = this.webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("{XPATH VALUE}"));

It prints out the other attributes' actual value

Comment: @RR_IL I am able to print out the actual values of the other attributes though

Comment: How are you assigning the value attribute? Are you dynamically assigning it in someway?

Comment: you're getting 0, but what are you expecting to see?

We're really lacking some context here.

Comment: @DMart the actual value of the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the JavascriptExecutor.

```
protected String getInputValue(WebElement element) {
String js = "return arguments[0].querySelector('input').value";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
return js.executeScript(js, element).toString();
}
```

Ref:
[Selenium Webdriver get input value which already has value attribute (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856175/selenium-webdriver-get-input-value-which-already-has-value-attribute-java)

Comment: I was able to tweak the value of String js to make my code work! I still do not understand why we have to enforce the use of JSExecutor though, but it did make my test work!